# insert or touchin private part

Tags: husband-wife, sexuality, intercourse

Assalamu Alaikum.
Can i insert my right hands finger into my wife vagina? Is it permissible to finger with the right hand if vaginal fluid (Madhy/Semen) comes out of the vagina while fingering the wife? The right hand can be stimulated better than the left hand.  So can a husband and wife touch each other's private part with the right hand, even if there is semen or impure fluid in the genitals?

Answer (score 0):

I think u had to find hadiths on using hands. Generally to be spoken, In hadiths left hand is seen to be used in seemingly impure activities. But it is better not to categoried all the impure activities that you take or think as impure to be thought as your left hand job. In hadiths which particular acts are mentioned u have to do those acts with Ur left hand. Outside of the domain of those mentioning acts,  u are not obliged to do with left though you take any of that to be impure. I recommend you this because in Islam Haram things are particular and mentioned or speial cases are also specific.

Answer (score 0):

as far as we are concerned in east Asia as Muslims, we are allowed to do that. especially if you have ED or other blockages from having it the proper way. as long as your wife wants to. I don't see any problem with this.

as you may know, some people are left-handed, while the rest are right-handed. I don't think such hadith will elaborate this act deeply but for me, it doesn't make sense if you're not allowed to do with right hand